# Can't install Grunt on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, homebrew

I'm new to this. I would like to use Grunt to run do some image optimalization. But I can't get it installed for some reason.

I've installed Homebrew by copying this in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I've also installed node on my system (by downloading the .pkg and installing it).

When I check if Homebrew and Node are installed I get this:

```
Joost:~ jvd$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
Joost:~ jvd$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

When I try to install Grunt by using this code: npm install -g grunt-cli i get (also when I use $ sudo)

```
Joost:~ jvd$ npm install -g grunt-cli
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Same goes for: npm update -g npm.

Like I said Im fairly new to this so most of the things I just searched on the web. But can't figure this out. Does somebody know what is wrong?

Thanks!
Joost

Comment: What's the output of `ls -laF /usr/local/bin/npm`?

Comment: http://thechangelog.com/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x/

Comment: Hi @GergoErdosi 
It gives: 
ls: /usr/local/bin/npm?: No such file or directory

Comment: Hi @gearsdigital Thanks for your message!

after I try `brew update` I get this:

`brew update
You must: brew install git
Error: Failure while executing: git init
Joost:~ jvd$ brew install git
Warning: Xcode is not installed. Most formulae need Xcode to build.
It can be installed from
  https://developer.apple.com/downloads
Error: git cannot be built with any available compilers.`

Comment: Install xcode ;) Or just go and grab the nodejs installer which has npm bundled -> http://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: @gearsdigital Thanks for your help! Will install XCode and see what happens ;) Let you know!

Comment: You can run `xcode-select --install` to install the Xcode Command Line Tools, which is a much smaller package that provides everything that almost all Homebrew packages need to build.

Comment: @TimSmith That worked like a charm! Thanks. Wierd thing is that when I try to check if Npm is up to date and running I get:

`Joost:~ jvd$ sudo npm update -g npm
sudo: npm: command not found`

but node -v gives:
`Joost:~ jvd$ node -v
v0.10.32`

Same goes for: 
`Joost:~ jvd$ npm install -g grunt-cli
-bash: npm: command not found`

Comment: @TimSmith

When I try brew doctor I get a lot of warnings including:

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    node

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Kind of stuk at this moment.

Comment: Tried this link: 
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-node-js-osx-10-9-mavericks/

Everything looks oke (even the javascript node session) but when I try to search for node packages `npm search` i get `-bash: npm: command not found` same goes for sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me a couple weeks ago:

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
$ sudo brew postinstall node
```

Might have to use sudo if you get any access errors. Sometimes installing node through homebrew causes errors. So another alternative would be to uninstall it and download the node.js package and install it yourself without homebrew.

Comment: Hi @A.Alger Thans for your answer. Tried it but wasn't able to resolve it. 

`brew update
You must: brew install git
Error: Failure while executing: git init
Joost:~ jvd$ brew uninstall node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node`

Comment: Try this: brew cleanup,
brew link node,
brew uninstall node,
brew install node,

Comment: Hi @a.alger Thanks for your comment tried it: 

Get the following response: 
`Joost:~ jvd$ brew cleanup
Joost:~ jvd$ brew link node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node`

Comment: Hi @A.Alger 

Installed Node through terminal but get this postinstall error.

`Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32: 1678 files, 19M
Joost:~ jvd$ brew postinstall node
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/AUTHORS`

Can't seem to fix it with `sudo brew postinstall node` any thoughts?

Thanks again! Joost

Comment: That's strange. The only option I would suggest is not using homebrew. Perhaps just uninstall it through brew, if you can, then install it from the file you can download from node.js. http://nodejs.org/